# Rationale for normalization of Weibull distribution?

Tags: weibull-distribution

I am reading a [paper](https://www.mssanz.org.au/modsim2017/D3/weir.pdf) which normalizes a Weibull distribution (equation 2):

$$
y_{ij} = \frac{
   1 - \exp \left[ - \left( \frac{t_j}{\beta} \right)^\alpha \right]
}{
   1 - \exp \left[ - \left( \frac{1}{\beta} \right)^\alpha \right]
}
$$

where $y_{ij}$  is  cumulative  expenditure  in  project $i$  at  time $t_j$.

I get that this is needed because of the infinite tail, but what is the thinking behind how the denominator is chosen?  Is this standard practice?  Where can I find (say) an online textbook describing this?

Comment: The paper is terribly written, so I can only guess that they appear to be *truncating* the distribution to the interval $t\in[0,1].$

Comment: I would have to agree that this is what they are doing, but I'm puzzled by why choose t=1 for the point of normalization.  In a subsequent paper that this author co-authored, the same normalization is used but t=1,2,...

Comment: Given that $y_{ij}$ is the proportion of total project budget expended at time $t_j$, it has to reach 1.00 at some final time $t_d$ in the project schedule. Therefore, I believe that the denominator can only be $ 1 - \exp [ - ( t_d / \beta ) ^\alpha] $.